# set attributions to WMTS Layer from capabilities in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I'm loading different layers from one WMTS source and want to display the correct attributions for the source of each layer.

In my code I define the attribution at the source-level for a `ol.layer.Tile`. The layer is later added to the map and display correct, but when I click the i-button on the map it only displays 'undefined'. In the console I don't get any errors.

```
var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();

  fetch('http://wmts1.geoportail.lu/opendata/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml').then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
    var result = parser.read(text);

    var hybrid_source = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
          layer: 'hybrid',
          matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857',
          attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
                    html: '<a href="https://data.public.lu" target="_blank">data.public.lu</a> Hybrid @ ACT Luxembourg'
                    })]
    });

    var hybrid_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
          opacity: 1.0,
          title: 'Hybrid',
          baseLayer: true,
          visible: true,              
          source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (hybrid_source))
        });
  });
```

Comment: I have the same problem now. Did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

meanwhile I simplified my code to load different WMTS layers in the following way.
This works fine for me and the attributions are displayed correctly.

```
    var baselayers = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Background-Layer',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'OSM',
                baseLayer: true,
                visible: false,
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
                        html: '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org" target="_blank">OpenstreetMap</a> OpenstreetMap'
                    })]
                    })
            }),

            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'Basemap HD',
                baseLayer: true,
                visible: false,
                extent: [636757.681558, 6351042.69913, 728716.389785, 6478379.8966],
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'https://wmts3.geoportail.lu/opendata/service?',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'basemap_hd'
                    },
                    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
                        html: '<br /><a href="https://data.public.lu" target="_blank">data.public.lu</a> Basemap HD @ ACT Luxembourg'
                    })],
                    serverType: 'geoserver'
                })
            })
        ]
     });

var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: view,
        layers: [baselayers]
    });
```